# Working with javascript method

Tags: javascript, methods

To get a value like '4,3' I have this:

```
var value = objeto.row(4).cell(3);
```

What's the correct form to develop the js method? I suppose I have to do something like that:

```
function objeto(rowIndex){
   cell: function(cellIndex){
      return rowIndex + ',' + cellIndex;
   }
}
```

I know it doesn't work, it is only a guess. Thank you...

Comment: Are you asking how to write code so that you can use the syntax in the first bit of code you provided to get "4,3"?

Comment: You have to add 2 methods to objeto prototype: `row()` will set the `this.row` value and return `this`, and `cell()` will return `this.row + "," + this.cell`. I guess.

Comment: you simple forget `row`, so you need something like this: `var objeto = { row : function (rowIndex){
  return { cell : function (cellIndex){
    return rowIndex+','+cellIndex;
  }}  
}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep a hierarchy where cells belong to rows, you could do this:

```
var objeto = {
    row: function ( rowIndex ) {
        return ( function ( rowIndex ) {
            this.cell = function ( cellIndex ) {
                return rowIndex + ',' + cellIndex;
            };
            return {
                cell: this.cell
            }
        }( rowIndex ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.cell` add `cell` function to `window` in your case :-)

Comment: Please note that you are creating or assigning to the global variable `cell` whenever the function is called. You should avoid that.

Comment: there is no need for the additional closure within the row method. the value of `rowIndex` is already preserved via the row method, which itself acts as a closure.

Comment: You guys are right, I was a bit trigger happy there. Grundy's answer would be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 3):

yet another way without adding internal function to `window`

```
var objeto = { 
    row : function (rowIndex){ 
        return { 
            cell : function (cellIndex){ 
                return rowIndex+','+cellIndex; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```